# Sci-fi type of show where a guy traveled in search of his wife and helped solve paranormal cases along the way

Tags: story-identification, tv, aliens

There was a sci-fi type of show I saw a some years ago, but can't recall the name or much about it, I just know I really liked it. In one of the episodes the main character (male) helps a couple who thinks they where abducted by aliens, but turns out they were hypnotized by some woman. There is also another episode I vaguely remember, where the main character got locked in some chamber with a pretty scientist and they had an hour or something to get out before all the air was sucked out or some poison was activated, not sure which one. I could have sworn the shows story line was the main character traveled in search of his wife and helped solve paranormal cases along the way. As I said I'm not so sure on the accuracy of any of this b/c I saw this show at least 5years ago when it was showing as a marathon.

Answer (score 6):

This sounds like it could be either Kolchak:Night Stalker, or it's remake simply titled Night Stalker.  Both where a television series about a reporter named Carl Kolchak who investigates crimes that have a supernatural element to them.  In the remade series Kolchak's wife was murdered and he investigates other murders he thinks are linked to his wife's.  There where also a couple made for tv movies connected to the original series, one called The Night Stalker, and another called The Night Strangler.  The original series and tv movies where from the early to mid 70's, and the remake series was in 2005.

Comment: Definatley not the first version of the Night Stalker series, but the 2005 remake sounds about right.

Answer (score 4):

Or possibly The Phoenix, maybe showing as a marathon.  The Phoenix was from the 80's, and I believe the main character was looking for his wife and also helped people in each episode.

Answer (score 3):

This television series is likely [*First Wave*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_Wave_(TV_series)) (1998-2001):

> Framed for murder [of his wife] and on the run, a former thief struggles to expose the vanguard of an alien invasion with the help of a conspiracy theorist and newly discovered prophecies of Nostradamus.
>
> — [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0160277/)

The series' title refers to the first wave of invasion by an alien species known as the Gua, who infiltrated Earth society by transferring recordings of their minds into artificial human bodies.

Your description of one of the episodes...

> In one of the episodes the main character (male) helps a couple who thinks they where abducted by aliens, but turns out they were hypnotized by some woman.

...matches the plot of "Hypnotic" (season 1, episode 4):

> A quatrain leads Cade to a rural area where a best-selling psychiatrist is helping people to to deal with alien encounters through hypnotic regression. Posing as a new member, he reaches out to the others in the group and investigates the psychiatrist -- who seems to be using the group as fodder for her next best-seller. He is convinced that the Gua are controlling the group for their own purposes -- but is it the doctor or one of the members in therapy? Along the way he grapples with the return of the Hannah clone, and helps out a young couple who were victims of another Gua experiment. He finds out that their memories have been tampered with by the Gua and uses a relaxation technique to help learn what really happened to them.
>
> — [IMDB](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0579744/plotsummary)